# How to send json response back in adonis js with a status code like 401?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I am trying to send a json response back to the application with a status code. This what I tired but didn't work.

```
if (validation.fails()) {
    console.log(validation.messages())
    return response.json(validation.messages(),false,401) 
    // or return response.json(validation.messages(),401)
   // It always sends 200 status code 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution. I need to use like this `return response.status(401).json(validation.messages())`

Answer (score 0):

One better solution is to use descriptive methods: https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/response#_descriptive_methods

Example:

```
response.unauthorized('Login First')
```